# Losing position of a specific item when I switch to landscape mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working with an application, whereas the purpose of it is to keep track of a list of words a person might be interested in learning. The app is split up into 3 activities, in which the first activity (ListActivity) shows a list of words with a few infos (image, word, pronounciation and rating) about each word. Image, word and pronounciation datas are already known and are hardcoded (I know that it would be much better if I just read data from a csv-file but let it be for now), and rating can be set from the EditActivity.

In that context I've implemented code that handles clicks on a specific word that will navigate me to 2nd activity (DetailsActivity) with all relevant infos from the particular word, aswell as retrieving rating data and display at the correct index/item. The code works and everything seems to be fine, but there's a bug, which I really can't solve.

The bug occurs when I do the following:

1. I click on a particular word in the recyclerview
2. I edit the word and give it a rating of 8 and press OK. Data will now be sent to ListActivity and will be shown at the correct index/word.
3. I press on the same word and switch to landscape mode and choose to edit the word. Let's say that I now give it a rating of 5 and press OK.
4. The new rating data will then be set/shown at index 0 and not the particular word.

What might be the issue here? It seems like it loses position somewhere in the application and between intents, but I can't figure out why.

**ListActivity:**

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WordAdapter.OnItemListener {

    ArrayList<WordItemParcelable> mWords = new ArrayList<WordItemParcelable>();
    private WordAdapter mAdapter;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_DETAILS_ACTIVITY = 1;
    private Button exitBtn;
    private String rating, note;
    private int wordClickedIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mWords = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(getString(R.string.key_orientationchange));
        } else {
            mWords = new ArrayList<>();
            insertWords();
        }
        setUpExitBtn();
        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    public void insertWords() {
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.lion, "Lion", "ˈlīən", "A large tawny-coloured cat that lives in prides, found in Africa and NW India. The male has a flowing shaggy mane and takes little part in hunting, which is done cooperatively by the females.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.leopard, "Leopard", "ˈlepərd", "A large solitary cat that has a fawn or brown coat with black spots, native to the forests of Africa and southern Asia.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.cheetah, "Cheetah", "ˈCHēdə", "A large slender spotted cat found in Africa and parts of Asia. It is the fastest animal on land.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.elephant, "Elephant", "ˈeləfənt", "A very large plant-eating mammal with a prehensile trunk, long curved ivory tusks, and large ears, native to Africa and southern Asia. It is the largest living land animal.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.giraffe, "Giraffe", "jəˈraf", "A large African mammal with a very long neck and forelegs, having a coat patterned with brown patches separated by lighter lines. It is the tallest living animal.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.kudo, "Kudu", "ˈko͞odo͞o", "An African antelope that has a greyish or brownish coat with white vertical stripes, and a short bushy tail. The male has long spirally curved horns.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.gnu, "Gnu", "n(y)o͞o", "A large dark antelope with a long head, a beard and mane, and a sloping back.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.oryx, "Oryx", "null", "A large antelope living in arid regions of Africa and Arabia, having dark markings on the face and long horns.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.camel, "Camel", "ˈkaməl", "A large, long-necked ungulate mammal of arid country, with long slender legs, broad cushioned feet, and either one or two humps on the back. Camels can survive for long periods without food or drink, chiefly by using up the fat reserves in their humps.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.shark, "Shark", "SHärk", "A long-bodied chiefly marine fish with a cartilaginous skeleton, a prominent dorsal fin, and tooth-like scales. Most sharks are predatory, though the largest kinds feed on plankton, and some can grow to a large size.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.crocodile, "Crocodile", "ˈkräkəˌdīl", "A large predatory semiaquatic reptile with long jaws, long tail, short legs, and a horny textured skin.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.snake, "Snake", "snāk", "A long limbless reptile which has no eyelids, a short tail, and jaws that are capable of considerable extension. Some snakes have a venomous bite.", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.buffalo, "Buffalo", "ˈbəf(ə)ˌlō", "A heavily built wild ox with backward-curving horns, found mainly in the Old World tropics:", "" + 0.0));
        mWords.add(new WordItemParcelable(R.drawable.ostrich, "Ostrich", "ˈästriCH", "A flightless swift-running African bird with a long neck, long legs, and two toes on each foot. It is the largest living bird, with males reaching a height of up to 2.75 m.", "" + 0.0));
    }

    public void setUpRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new WordAdapter(mWords, this);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
         WordItemParcelable clickedWord = mWords.get(position);
        wordClickedIndex = position;

        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_picture), clickedWord.getImageResource());
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_name), clickedWord.getWord());
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_pronouncing), clickedWord.getPronouncing());
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_description), clickedWord.getDescription());
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_rating), clickedWord.getRating());
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_notes), clickedWord.getNotes());

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_DETAILS_ACTIVITY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_DETAILS_ACTIVITY) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {

                   rating = data.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.key_rating));
                   note = data.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.key_notes));

                    WordItemParcelable i = mWords.get(wordClickedIndex);
                    i.setRating(rating);

                    mWords.set(wordClickedIndex, i);
                    mAdapter.updateData(mWords);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setUpExitBtn() {
        exitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);

        exitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(getString(R.string.key_orientationchange), mWords);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class WordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordAdapter.WordViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<WordItemParcelable> mWordList;
    private OnItemListener mOnItemListener;
    private int position;

    public static class WordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView mPicture;
        TextView txtName, txtPronouncing, txtRating;
        OnItemListener onItemListener;
        private int position;

        public WordViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemListener onItemListener) {
            super(itemView);

            mPicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNameOfTheWord);
            txtPronouncing = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPronoucing);
            txtRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtListRating);
            this.onItemListener = onItemListener;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onItemListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }


    public WordAdapter(ArrayList<WordItemParcelable> wordList, OnItemListener onItemListener) {
        this.mWordList = wordList;
        this.mOnItemListener = onItemListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.word_item, parent, false);
        WordViewHolder wvh = new WordViewHolder(v, mOnItemListener);
        return wvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
        WordItemParcelable word = mWordList.get(position);

        int image = word.getImageResource();
        String name = word.getWord();
        String pronounce = word.getPronouncing();
        String rating = word.getRating();

        holder.mPicture.setImageResource(image);
        holder.txtName.setText(name);
        holder.txtPronouncing.setText(pronounce);
        holder.txtRating.setText(rating);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mWordList.size();

    }

    public interface OnItemListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<WordItemParcelable> newList) {
        mWordList = newList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When changing the orientation of the screen, activity is recreated to save information, use onsaveinstancestate: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   position = savedInstanceState.getInteger(KEY);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
outState.putString(KEY, position);

super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

(This is pseudo code, there may be errors)